# net maui - play default notification sound/beep (android)

Tags: android, .net, notifications, maui

How to play a system sound in .Net Maui, for example for a notification beep?

Maybe with platform specific code for Android if needed.

A complete status notification is not needed, just the beep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RingtoneManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.media.ringtonemanager?view=net-android-34.0) provides access to ringtones, notification, and other types of sounds.
To use it, you may [Invoke platform code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/invoke-platform-code?view=net-maui-8.0) for Android,

Suppose we play a system notification sound when we click a button

```
    private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

#if ANDROID
        var instance = Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Platform.CurrentActivity;
        Android.Net.Uri uri = RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Notification);
        Ringtone rt = RingtoneManager.GetRingtone(instance.ApplicationContext, uri);
        rt.Play();
#endif
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Is there a way to play the sound on the alarm clock channel of the phone?

Comment: When using .net8-android34.0, I get error CS0234 "The type or namespace name 'Net' does not exist in the namespace".

Comment: Which line throw the error? Just tested on Android api34 and it works fine,

Answer (score 1):

There's multiple ways of doing this, the simplest cross platform one is to embed a beep audio file into your project and then use the media element from the MAUI community toolkit to play it, simply using:

```
mediaElement.Play();
```

Here's a link to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/mediaelement)